# install gcc on MAC 10.7.4

Tags: macos, qt, gcc

I am trying to install `QtCreator` on my `MacProbook (10.7.4)`. QtCreator needs `gcc`.
Can any one suggest how to install `gcc` on `Mac 10.7.4`

Comment: Does it require gcc or just a c++ compiler - OSXs default is clang++

Answer (score 0):

Installing [*Command Line Tools for Xcode*](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) will get you gcc. Another way is using [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).

Comment: macports needs the command line tools as well

Comment: Oh, thanks for the notice. Removed macports from the answer.